# Deleting a key in JSON Array of Object

Tags: json, angularjs

What if I will delete a key in a json with an array of objects,what will happen after a certain execution? Will the json retain the previous data/keys or the deleted key will not be visible anymore after deleting it.
See the json example below.

```
jsonX= [
    {
     "id":"01",
     "name":"item1",
     "address":"Xxx City"         
    },     
    {
     "id":"02",
     "name":"item2",
     "address":"Yyy City"         
    },
    {
     "id":"03",
     "name":"item3",
     "address":"Zzz City"         
    }
];
```

a certain method will have this code:

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < jsonX.length ; i++){
    delete jsonX[i].id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is yes it will remove the id from the object, but you have wrong your jsonX declaration this code will fix it

```
jsonX=[
{
    "id": "01",
    "name": "item1",
    "address": "Xxx City"
},
{
    "id": "02",
    "name": "item2",
    "address": "Yyy City"
},
{
    "id": "03",
    "name": "item3",
    "address": "Zzz City"
}];
```

Comment: Thanks bro. just switched the '{}' and the '[]' in the sample. :)
If I will copy jsonX to another object before I remove id, will that affect the other object's data also?